# Suppress bulleting in itemize environment

Tags: lists, itemize

I have  a nested list, and I wish to suppress any bullet/diamond/hyphen that appears only in the sub-list.

For example:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item blah
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item a 
\item b
\item c 
\item d
\item e
\item f
\item g
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\item blah... 
\end{itemize}
```

I dont want anything to be prefixed to the a,b,c,d,... sublist.

Is there any way to do this, other than creating the sub-list as a table rather than an itemized list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to force the label to `{}` (making it empty):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item blah
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \raggedcolumns
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
      \item a 
      \item b
      \item c 
      \item d
      \item e
      \item f
      \item g
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
  \item blah... 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\raggedcolumns` to allow non-uniform columns, as provided by the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol). The above (nested) list has a separation between the empty label and the item. If you want to get rid of this, add the option `labelsep=0pt` to the list arguments. The same goes for the margin indent. Read the [`enumitem` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) to see the different lengths used in typesetting any item. It may depend on the context of your lists.

Answer (score 10):

How about using the `enumitem` package and specifying

```
\setlist[itemize,2]{label={}}
```

(With the "2" specifier, labels of level-2 itemize lists will not have a symbol prefixed; other list levels will not be affected.)

If you don't want to load the `enumitem` package, you could simply reset the `\labelitemii` macro as follows

```
\renewcommand\labelitemii{}
```

to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 10):

Every item you want without bullet must be like this:

```
\item[] a
```

This works without any additional package loaded.

So your list will be like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item blah
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item[] a
      \item[] b
      \item[] c
      \item[] d
      \item[] e
      \item[] f
      \item[] g
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
  \item blah...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: This post from [SO] may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522753/how-do-i-hide-bullets-in-latex-lists